# Is it possible to change the smoke colour without clearing the cache?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

Is it possible to change the smoke colour attribute in Cycles, without having to clear the cache and rebake?

Comment: If color is set in the smoke material, it should work changing it from there (so without connecting **Attribute** node with value *Color* rather than using color palette right there).

Comment: @MrZak That only helps if all your smoke is the same color. Perhaps you could change the colors of the color attribute with nodes though

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to have a few different smoke colors missing. Maybe editing the smoke cache file directly?

Comment: Oops: I meant mixing*

Comment: The color attribute comes in via a node, so maybe there is a way to manipulate it then?

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ as long as there's a way so distinguish between multiple smoke flow objects, that'd be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This does not appear to be possible.**

Hopefully in future the smoke system will output a mix factor for the smoke instead of a color, as then the colors of the smoke would be fully editable. Currently the output is the actual RGB color so this is not possible.